# How to see the dependency tree just from Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am getting the following error when doing `bundle install`

```
Make sure that `gem install couchbase -v '1.3.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Now, i have not included this gem in the `Gemfile`, so it's coming from some dependency. How can i figure out which gem is dependent on this couchbase gem?

Since `bundle install` is failing and I don't have `Gemfile.lock` to figure out this dependency.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`gem dependency` (with no args) should show you all gems from current system with their dependencies.

`bundle exec gem dependency` will show you for the current Gemfile

**Edit:**

You can also do `gem dependency -R` (or just `dep` instead of `dependency`) if you want to find out which gems use specific (or all) gems.

For deeper dependencies I'd parse output (regex maybe?) of first gem dependencies, pick gem's names and call `gem dep` on each of them, but that's just a loose idea.

Comment: Thnx. This answers my question. Strange but 'gem dependency' is showing that no gem is dependent on 'couchbase'. Any idea why bundle install is trying to install it even though none of the gem is dependent on it ?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know, what happens if you w'd try installing that gem by hand? Also, can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: I can install gemfile on local, but while deployment or running CI it will bomb.

Comment: "gem dependency" only shows 1st level of dependency, any idea how to see nested dependencies ?

Comment: @MohitVerma why don't you take a look at your local `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: @MohitVerma: so you **do** have `Gemfile.lock`, why won't check it?

Comment: @Stefan, bundle install is failing, so i am not able to generate Gemfile.lock

Comment: You said *"I can install gemfile on local"*

Comment: Somehow, not able to install it locally also. couchbase gem needs few more things on machine :( Any other option ?

Comment: `gem dependency` has nothing to do with your current `Gemfile`.  It just looks at the installed gems on the system.

Comment: If the dependency generation fails, you don't get a `Gemfile.lock` to look at. All that happens is that "bundle install" fails trying to install some random gem that is not listed in your Gemfile. In this situation, as far as I can tell, the only way to find out *why* bundle was even trying to install that gem in the first place is to somehow get all the gems in the Gemfile installed successfully so you can run `gem dependency --reverse-dependencies` on it.

Comment: `gem dependency` is also showing me dependencies for things that are NOT in `~/Gemfile`. This makes the results very unhelpful.

Comment: `bundle exec gem dependency` will use the`Gemfile` gems.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use [bundler](http://bundler.io/) to create a dependency graph.

Install graphviz:

```
gem install ruby-graphviz
```

and then:

```
bundle viz
```

Here are an example of a newly created Rails app:

[image: Rails app dependency graph]

You can also play with the options:

```
bundle help viz
```

Comment: If you don’t have Graphviz but you do have Homebrew, you can `brew install graphviz`.

Comment: `bundle viz -vR` will create the dependency graph with the gem version and the required dependency version

Comment: it's great but the generated png file is hardly readable. One would have to guess what's written there.