# Can you find out where a library was required from?

Tags: ruby

Background - in a Rails app, I'm seeing a bug in production where a file cannot find a class from the standard library; but in development, everything works fine. Presumably, some gem that I have in the development group but not the production group is requiring the necessary library, so the symbol is define for development but not for production.

Is there any way I can get Ruby to tell me where `require` was called for a given file?

(I'm deliberately not naming the offending library, because I *don't* want suggestions as to what might be requiring it; I want to know how I can find out myself)

Comment: How about just running `gem dependency`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050654/how-to-see-the-dependency-tree-just-from-gemfile

Comment: How does the bug look like? Doesn't it contain a stack trace pointing to the `require`?

Comment: Honestly, I'd just look for clues based on the undefined class/method name and the context of the code. (Neither of which are in your post.) You could probably even just google the error and see what pops up....

Comment: @lacostenycoder assuming I understand that correctly, it won't give what I want (the missing require is not a gem, but part of the standard library)

Comment: @Stefan No - the bug is a `NameError` - `Uninitialized constant`, due to referencing something defined in the library.

Comment: @TomLord Indeed, I did that and eventually found the gems responsible by grepping their github repos. But there were 5 of them, so getting a list programmatically would definitely have helped!

Comment: What would also help is organising the `Gemfile` into groups of development/test gems, and writing comments to make it clear what each library is for. I don't normally advocate writing comments in code, but `Gemfile`s are certainly an exception to the rule IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your direct question: patch/override the `require` method and get access to all the info you need.

#### app/config/environment.rb

```
# set up intrumentation
module RequireSpy
  def require(*args)
    puts "requiring #{args.join(', ')} from #{caller.first}"
    super
  end
end
Object.include(RequireSpy)

# init your rails app as usual
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Upon booting the rails app, it'll print a LOT of output:

```
requiring tilt from /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
requiring rack/protection from /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
requiring thread from /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
requiring time from /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
requiring uri from /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
```

You probably want to filter that.