# rubocop will not run getting errors related to cookstyle

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, rubocop

I am getting this when I run a barebones rubocop.

```
gem list | egrep 'rubocop|cookstyle'
cookstyle (7.10.0)
rubocop (1.12.1, 1.12.0)
rubocop-ast (1.4.1)
rubocop-performance (1.10.2)

The error follows upon running rubocop with no parameters:

Unable to activate cookstyle-7.10.0, because rubocop-1.12.1 conflicts with rubocop (= 1.12.0)
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2298:in `raise_if_conflicts'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1415:in `activate'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:224:in `rescue in try_activate'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:217:in `try_activate'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in resolve_requires'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:13:in `each'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:13:in `block in resolve_requires'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:12:in `tap'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader_resolver.rb:12:in `resolve_requires'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:45:in `load_file'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:106:in `configuration_from_file'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:69:in `for_dir'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:48:in `for_pwd'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:128:in `apply_default_formatter'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:40:in `run'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/exe/rubocop:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.9/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/gems/rubocop-1.12.1/exe/rubocop:12:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/Users/stuartcracraft/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.9/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried removing either rubocop version but got the same error.

I am trying to find a way to lint chef ruby code, hence the above attempt.

If anyone sees anything in the above errors or has another linter with a smoother
install, please let me know.

Thanks.

Stuart

Comment: try removing `rubocop = 1.12.0` only, and not `1.12.1`. If doesn't work, try removing all gems that depend on them (the tree of dependencies) and add them back. `gem dependency -R` ( [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050654/how-to-see-the-dependency-tree-just-from-gemfile) )

Answer (score 0):

Version conflicts are typically resolved with bundler. Try `bundle exec rubocop`.